# pass multiple values

Tags: jsp, servlets

I want to pass these two values to the servlet (Delete) by clicking this button. But this is not working. How can I do this?

```
<input id="delete" type="button" name="delete" value="Delete"
     onclick="var val=confirm('Do You want to delete ? '); location.href='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Delete?value='+val +'?id='+<%=rs.getInt("id")%>">
```

In the servlet it is taking only one value.

Comment: How do you receive values in servlet?

Comment: i got value as a String and id as a String. But gives value = true?id=6 like this.

Comment: Could it be possible to post your code?

Comment: <input id="delete" type="button" name="delete" value="Delete"
                           onclick="var val=confirm('Do You want to delete ? ');
                               location.href='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Delete?value='+val+'id='+<%=rs.getInt("id")%>"></td>

Comment: And what is not being passed?

Comment: i want to get id and value seperately.like this, id=5 And value = true/fale

Comment: I assume that `rs‌​.getInt("id")` gives you 5 right?  and how true/false is being passed? variable val contains true/false?

Answer (score 0):

I think the `location.href` should be as follows:

```
location.href='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Delete?value=' + val + '&id=' +<%=rs.getInt("id")%>"
```

Notice the `&id=` instead of the `?id=`.

In a particular URL `?` is used just once to separate the `path` from the `parameters` and `&` is used to send multiple values.

For example, try searching the string "mySearch" in `google.com` and you will see a url generated as:

> http://www.google.co.in/search?q=mysearch&rlz=1C1GGGE_enIN485IN485&oq=mysearch&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8
>
> Here `q`, `rlz`, `sugexp` ... etc are different request parameters separated by the `&` sign.

Also I hope in the servlet you are fetching it as `request.getParameter("value")` and `request.getParameter("id")`.